# Understanding the performance difference of two tail recursive map functions

Tags: recursion, ocaml, tail-recursion, map-function

From **Introduction to Objective Caml by Jason Hickey** , we have a tail recursive map function:

```
let rec rev_accum result = function  
    h::tl -> rev_accum (h :: result) tl
    | [] -> result

let rec rec_map f result = function
    h :: tl -> rec_map  f (f h :: result)   tl 
    | [] -> result 

let map1 f l = rev_accum  [] ( rec_map f [] l )
```

It will traverse the list twice.  Consider this alternative:

```
let rec rec_map2 f result = function
    h :: tl -> rec_map2  f ( result @[f h]) tl 
    | [] -> result 

let map2 f l = rec_map2 f [] l ;
```

Will the second one be faster than the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeatedly adding to the end of a list takes time that is quadratic in the final length of the list. Another way of saying this is that it traverses the list *n* times, which can easily be more than twice. So the second implementation will be much slower in general. The first implementation is linear, even though it traverses the list twice.

(Of course you don't know the performance of the function `f`.)

Comment: To my understand append a item to list. In C when it was implemented by link list, it is O(1), why ocaml need traverses the total list?

Comment: If your C code keeps a pointer to the last element of the list, then adding an element does not require list traversal. But with a singly linked list, you have a pointer to the head element only, thus appending to the list requires traversal.